# How to detect object on image

Tags: matlab

I have a problem to detect the green packet of crunches.

[image]

I have different images taken with different  focus settings, and so far I find where could be the object. But now I have a problem to detect the edges of the object, I try with first derivation of the Gaussian filter to detect the edges in x and y direction and try to combine but the result it is not very satisfy. I try to convert the pic to another color space to see more clear the edges, but with out result.

Comment: If you format the hyperlinks as such some of us will follow them.

Comment: Are you only trying to detect *green* objects?

Comment: no only green object, but in this case is green, maybe that can help because it have different color

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, you can try using [local features](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/object-detection-and-tracking.html).